# Link an ellipse annotation to two terms of an equation with two arrows

Tags: annotations, latex, equation

Is it possible to produce with latex an annotated equation like this one :

[image]

Which environment should I use ? The casual 'equation' environment, Tikz, both ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (0,0) {$M = \frac{A+B}{C \times D} + F + G$};
    \draw[thick, red, ->] (-0.5,0.5) -- (-.35,2);
    \draw[thick, red, ->] (0,0.5) -- (-.15,2);
    \draw[thick, ->] (0.7,-0.25) -- (1,-2);
    \draw[thick, ->] (1.3,-0.25) -- (1.1,-2);
    \node[draw=red, ellipse] at (-.2,2.5) {method 1};
    \node[ellipse,draw] at (1.1,-2.5) {method 2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: No way. The arrows are absolutely positioned, once the equation is revised, you have to tweak the coordinates again.